# Computed properties in controller in Ember

Tags: ember.js, computed-properties

I'm a raw beginner with Ember. The app is a sleep tracker. What I'm trying to build right now is the average number of hours slept and napped, over the past N days.

To calculate the average, I believe I want to add a computed property on the controller. I don't have a model yet, because the app is so raw.

Here is my current code:

```
// app/routes/home.js
import Ember from 'ember';

let events = [
  {
    "dow": 5,
    "durationInSeconds": 29280,
    "endAt": 1471087260000,
    "startAt": 1471057980000,
    "timezone": "America/Montreal"
  },
  { ... }
]

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model() {
    return events.sortBy("startAt").reverse();
  }
});

// app/controllers/home.js
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  averageNapDuration() {
    console.log("model: %o", this.get('model'));
    return 0;
  },

  averageNightDuration() {
    // TODO
  }
});

// app/templates/home.hbs
<table>
  ..
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <td scope="row" colspan="3">Average nap</td>
      <td class="duration">{{format-duration averageNapDuration}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td scope="row" colspan="3">Average night</td>
      <td class="duration">{{format-duration 22680}}</td>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```

My `format-duration` helper function does a `console.log` of the received values. When it's time to display the average, `format-duration` receives a function instead of a value.

I also failed to see the `console.log` call in the controller.

In the Handlebars template, I tried using:

```
{{format-duration averageNapDuration() }}
```

but this returns a syntax error:

```
Error: Parse error on line 48:
...">{{format-duration averageNapDuration()
-----------------------^
Expecting 'CLOSE_RAW_BLOCK', 'CLOSE', 'CLOSE_UNESCAPED', 'OPEN_SEXPR', 'CLOSE_SEXPR', 'ID', 'OPEN_BLOCK_PARAMS', 'STRING', 'NUMBER', 'BOOLEAN', 'UNDEFINED', 'NULL', 'DATA', 'SEP', got 'INVALID'
```

As another test, I changed my controller to use a computed property:

```
averageNapDuration: Ember.computed.sum('@each.durationInSeconds')
```

This time, the `format-duration` says it received 0, which indicates to me, that the template is at least talking to the controller correctly.

Where can I find examples of computed properties on filtered arrays? What must I change in the code above to calculate the sum of an integer?

Comment: If you want to use a computed property, why don't you read up on how to write them, either using `Ember.computed` or the `function() {}.computed` syntax? [The docs are clear enough](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.3.0/object-model/computed-properties/).

Comment: Wher is the format-duration helper? I think the understanding of that, is part of the problem. You should create a simplified ember-twiddle to get to the bottom of this.

Comment: @sheriffderek, the format-duration helper has no importance to the discussion at hand. It already correctly formats a plain value. The problem is exposed on this Twiddle: https://ember-twiddle.com/2596daefabd8a1e2d3439465b6f0df45. The nap function returns a plain value, and that is incorrectly displayed in the generated HTML. On the other hand, the night function returns a computed value, which is correctly displayed. Look at the console: night logs, while nap doesn't. I expected to be able to declare a function and have it execute when called from the template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This throws parse error.

```
{{format-duration averageNapDuration() }}
```

You can't call function in helper arguments. the below will work fine.

```
{{format-duration averageNapDuration }}
```

Your controller would be like,

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Controller.extend({
    averageNapDuration: Ember.computed('model', function() {
        console.log("model: %o", this.get('model'));
        //You can calculate avg nap duration and return the result
        return 0;
    }),
    //this computed property will be called for every durationInSeconds property changes
    averageNightDuration: Ember.computed('model.@each.durationInSeconds', function() {
        //You can calculate avg night slepp duration and return the result
    })
});
```

If we use the dependant key as `model.[]` then computed property will be called for every time event is added/removed and changed to brand new different array.

If we use the dependant key as `model.@each.durationInSeconds` then computed property will be called for every time `durationInSeconds` property changes and also for every event time event is added/removed to `model`. and entire `model` property is changed to brand new different array.

Ember guides link for [computed properties](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.10.0/object-model/computed-properties/) and [Computed Properties and Aggregate Data](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.10.0/object-model/computed-properties-and-aggregate-data/) will explain better.

Comment: It's unlikely that it will be correct to make `averageNapDuration` dependent on `model`. That will recalculate only when the model object itself changes, not its contents.

Comment: @torazaburo, you are correct. I need to react on changes to the values of `model.@each.durationInSeconds` and to the addition and removal of rows as well. Thanks!